# Overriding the legend title using user specified string instead of variable name

Tags: legend, legend-properties

I have a  below code using ggplot2() package. I am trying to plot between the variables - 'Company Advertising' and 'Brand Revenue' of my data frame 'htmltable' , when the another variable 'Industry' is 'Luxury'; using ggplot() function. I am using another variable of my data frame 'Brand Value' as colour variable.

```
p<- ggplot(htmltable[htmltable$Industry='Luxury',],aes(x='CompanyAdvertising',y='BrandRevenue')

q <- p+geom_point(aes(color='BrandValue',size='BrandValue') + geom_text(label='Brand')

r <- q+xlab("Company Advertisiment in Billions")+ylab("Brand Revenue in Billions") +ggtitle("Luxury")

r+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=10,face='bold'),legend.key=element_rect(fill='light blue'))
```

Here, I want to change my legend title from "BrandValue" to "BrandValue in Billions". Please suggest.

I tried using labs parameter in the below statement. But it is resulting in 2 legends.

```
r <- q+xlab("Company Advertisiment in Billions")+ylab("Brand Revenue in Billions") +ggtitle("Luxury")+labs(colour="BrandValue in Billions")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
   +labs(colour="BrandValue in Billions",
          size="BrandValue in Billions")
```

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"